# Who are the architects of the buildings on which these fictional buildings were based?

Tags: inspiration, thaddeus-howze

The short story ["The Woman Who Fell in Love with a Postmodern Building and Set Her Lovers’ Boat on Fire"](https://medium.com/@ebonstorm/the-woman-who-fell-in-love-with-a-postmodern-building-and-set-her-lovers-boat-on-fire-535fcac4507d) by Thaddeus Howze features three buildings:

1. **Churchill**
   [image: Picture of a church]

   > (...) an old world church in New York, (...) Churchill,
2. **Pierce**
   [image: picture of a house]

   > (...) Pierce, her home on the bay in Quincy, Massachusetts.
3. **Karls**
   [image: picture of a word shaped building in Prague]

   > (...) all curves and sharp angles in the sun, deliberate — steel and glass, concrete and rebar.
   >
   > (...)
   >
   > Made by an eccentric architect who, soon after completing Karls, went quietly mad. Karls was the personification of said madness, twisted, distorted, his inner spirit matched his outer appearance.

The buildings shown are the ones that inspired the ones in the story, courtesy of the author.

**So which buildings are these, and who were the architects?**

Comment: There are reverse image search engines: https://www.imageraider.com/ and https://www.tineye.com/

Comment: Such a shame @Thaddeus didn't answer this one... :-)

Comment: I approve those answers, Rand. I would have done the heavy lifting but my son was having issues and couldn't get back to it in a timely fashion. I am happy to see "The Stack Provides."

Comment: @Thaddeus I hope you like seeing your very own tag. I'll leave filling in the tag wiki to you. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first one is the ["Wedding palace church"](http://sthughofcluny.org/2013/07/the-churches-of-new-york-xlii-the-wedding-palace-church.html) designed by [Thomas Poole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Henry_Poole) in 1886 and it's located in the New York

I've found little about the 2nd one, but it has been designed by [Sam Van Dam](http://www.vandamdesign.com/about/samuel_van_dam.html) and it's a ["coastal estate in Maine"](http://www.vandamdesign.com/work/residential/coastal.html)

The 3rd one is called ["the dancing house" or "Fred and Ginger"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_House) (From Fred Astair and Ginger Rogers) and it's located in Prague, Czech republic, designed by [Vlado Milunić](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlado_Miluni%C4%87) and [Frank Gehry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Gehry) in 1992.